# Automated deployment and configuration managment

Tags: 2007, deployment, migration

We are having a MOSS 2007 environment and usually do not support custom development. However, we extensively do customization of sites via SharePoint designer including JavaScript and SPServices. We have three environments DEV, STAGE and PROD for SharePoint and sometimes its a pain to copy all data from one environment to another. Is there an automated solution for moving sites from one environment to another? We also leverage Hudson build deployment server for some .Net code but never tried for SharePoint. Please let me know if that is feasible and/or possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use standard SharePoint OOTB utility "STSADM". This can be found in 12 folder (C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\12\BIN for standard installation path).

Use restore/backup command to backup and restore entire site collections. This will do full restore of the site collection. Do not forget to change site colletion administrators when restore is done.

Or you can use export/import command useful more for content migration without affecting user permissions and settings of the site collection.

These links can be useful:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263441(v=office.12).aspx

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262087(v=office.12).aspx

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288940(v=office.12).aspx

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc287920(v=office.12).aspx

Hope it helps,

Andrew

Comment: Ah. I forgot my best friend stsadm.