# Farm Backup vs Granular Backup - SP 2010

Tags: 2010, backup, server-farm

I am using SharePoint 2010 and I only have 1 Site Collection.

In my CA I can do a Farm Backup or a Granular Backup.

What must I used, I just want to make a full backup of everything including all the content in my Site Collection.

If something go wrong, I want to be able to restore everything the way it was.

Answer (score 1):

The Farm Backup alternative is meant to be used in the scenario you descibes: When you want to backup everything in the farm in one backup.

Granular backup is used for backing up a specific sharepoint entity, like a sitecollection, web or a list.

Comment: If you do a Farm backup, will that also do a backup of all the content saved in my database?

Comment: Yes, in most cases, see this link http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee428295(v=office.14).aspx under Considerations for some special considerations that you have to take into account though.

Answer (score 0):

if you need to have a backup I can advise you to use stsamd utility installed with SharePoint. This is much more stable than using UI.

I have answered similar question [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/64625/automated-deployment-and-configuration-managment/64633#64633).

hope it helps you,

Andrew