# How can I backup and restore a site collection in SP2010?

Tags: site-collection, backup, restore

I have a sharepoint 2010 portal. I have a farm, with inside of it some site collections. One of these site collections ok. I would like to create a new site collection and restore a backup of the old site collection. How can I do this?

Comment: http://lmgtfy.com/?q=backup+sharepoint+2010+sitecollection&l=1

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is via SharePoint 2010 Management Shell:
http://www.bradleyschacht.com/backup-and-restore-sharepoint-2010-site-collection-with-powershell/

Or you can take a backup of Site Collection in Central Administration tool and restore it using Management Shell/PowerShell:
http://blogen.siderys.com/2010/02/how-to-do-backup-and-restore-in.html

Answer (score 0):

There is not just one way to do this and you could use custom tools.
BTW some useful links:

[Backup and recovery overview (SharePoint Server 2010)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ee663490%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

[Plan for backup and recovery in SharePoint Server 2010](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261687%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I have already answered the same question several times...

Try o see [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/66856/farm-backup-vs-granular-backup-sp-2010/66871#66871) one.

Hope it helps you,

Andrew

Answer (score 0):

You can use stsadm or directly bacpup-spsite command from powershell.

run as admin mode

for more info pls check
 [Site collection Backup and restore command](http://navoneel23.blogspot.in/2013/01/site-collection-backup-and-restore-in.html)